# Why do we need to call "build()" for Uri.Builder object to pass in URL constructor?

Tags: java, android, url, uri

I'm learning URL right now, and I get confused when I am building the Uri and pass it into the URL constructor.

I found that most of people use `build()` for the Uri.Builder object and then pass it (using `toString()`) into the URL constructor. However, I found that I can just pass my UriBuilder object and use `toString()` into the URL constructor, which also works. So, what's the differences? What's the pros and cons?

```
public static URL buildUrl(String githubSearchQuery) {
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon();

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(PARAM_QUERY, githubSearchQuery);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(PARAM_SORT, sortBy);

    //Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(uriBuilder.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return url;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`java.net.URL`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java6/index.html?java/net/URL.html) has overloaded constructors : one of them accepts an URI and another accepts a String.
So both are valid :

```
url = new URL(uriBuilder.toString()); // pass a String
url = new URL(uriBuilder.build());  //  pass an android.net.Uri
```

This works in both cases because  [`UriBuilder.toString()` is overrided to](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java) render the current building URI in its textual classic format :

```
  public String toString() {
        @SuppressWarnings("StringEquality")
        boolean cached = cachedString != NOT_CACHED;
        if (cached) {
            return cachedString;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(scheme).append(':');
        sb.append(getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart());
        if (!fragment.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append('#').append(fragment.getEncoded());
        }
        return cachedString = sb.toString();
    }
```

But this is a kind of trick because `toString()` even if not likely could change its implementation in a next version that would not allow you to pass it as a valid textual URI to the URL constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much!